# Symplectic form on the n-torus

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry

I am trying to show that the n-torus, $\mathbb{R}^{2n}/ \mathbb{Z}^{2n}$ always has a symplectic form.

By the Quotient Manifold Theorem, we have a smooth structure on the n-torus and a covering map $\pi \colon \mathbb{R}^{2n}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}/ \mathbb{Z}^{2n}$.

Then, we have an open covering of the n-torus and in each open we can define a symplectic form by passing the symplectic form of an open of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ by a diffeomorphism.

However, I am having troubles to understand why the symplectic form is defined globally; i.e, why it varies smoothly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the symplectic form $ \omega=dx_1\wedge dx_2+...+dx_{2n-1}\wedge dx_{2n}$ it is preserved by the translations of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ so it defines a symplectic form $\Omega$ on $T^{2n}$ such that if $p:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\rightarrow T^{2n}$ is the quotient map, $p^*\Omega=\omega$.

Comment: I think that I understand it! So since $T_{\pi(p)}(\mathbb{R}^{2n}/ \mathbb{Z}^{2n})$ is isomorphic to $T_{p}\mathbb{R}^{2n}/(\mathbb{Z}^{2n}\cdot p)$, I define $w_{\pi(p)}$ in$ ([u],[v])$ as $w_{p}(u,v)$?

Comment: something like so, if $p:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\rightarrow T^{2n}$ is the quotient map, let $x\in T^{2n}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ such that $p(y)=x$. Let $u,v\in T_xT^{2n}$ and $u',v'\in T_y\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ such that $dp_y(u')=u, dp_y(v')=v$, $\Omega_x(u,v)=\omega_y(u',v')$.